# Inconsistent parameter pack deduction with variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I have the following C++11 example where I have a `call` function that uses variadic templates to accept and call a generic class method:

```
#include <utility>

template <typename T, typename R, typename... Args>
R call(R (T::*fn)(Args...), T *t, Args&&... args) {
    return ((*t).*fn)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);    
}

class Calculator {
    public:
    int add(const int& a, const int& b) {
        return a + b;
    }
};

int main() {
    Calculator *calculator = new Calculator();
    int* a = new int(2);    
    int* b = new int(4);

    // compiles
    int res1 = calculator->add(*a, *b);    

    // does not compile!
    int res2 = call<Calculator>(&Calculator::add,calculator, *a, *b);    

    return 0;
}
```

As commented in the code, I'm not able to pass an `int` when the function accept `const int`, while in the direction method call I can. I get the following compile error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘call(int (Calculator::*)(const int&, const int&), Calculator*&, int&, int&)’
     int res2 = call<Calculator>(&Calculator::add,calculator, *a, *b);    
                                                                    ^

inconsistent parameter pack deduction with ‘const int&’ and ‘int&’
     int res2 = call<Calculator>(&Calculator::add,calculator, *a, *b);    
                                                                    ^
```

Does the C++ variadic template enforce stricter type checking when compared to regular execution? I'm using g++ 4.8.1 with C++ 11.

Comment: Maybe you'll like Clang's error better: *note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter 'Args' (<const int &, const int &> vs. <int &, int &>)*

Comment: So does that mean that the types have to match exactly when using variadic templates?

Comment: It means you can't deduce different types for the same template parameter because the compiler can't know which you want. You could always skip out on the explicit function capture and just have a callable object parameter: `template <typename F, typename T, typename... Args>
auto call(F f, T *t, Args&&... args) {
    return (t->*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);    
}`

Comment: @chris: how would my caller side look like with this approach? What should I pass as argument for type `F`?

Comment: Simply remove the explicit template argument.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The way you are calling your function template, the template parameter pack `Args` will be deduced from two sources:

- The type of the pointer to member function - `int (Calculator::*)(const int&, const int&)`
- The actual types of the arguments (`*a, *b)` you passed for the function parameter pack - `int &, int &`

For deduction to succeed, the result deduced must exactly match. They obviously don't.

This isn't new or special to variadic templates. You have the same issue if you try to do `std::max(1, 1.5)` - the compiler deduces `int` from one argument, `double` from the other, and deduction fails because the two conflict.

Simplest fix is probably taking two packs:

```
template <typename T, typename R, typename... Args1, typename... Args2>
R call(R (T::*fn)(Args1...), T *t, Args2&&... args) {
    return ((*t).*fn)(std::forward<Args2>(args)...);    
}
```